# In PowerPoint VBA, how to nudge all the present shapes in the window (not only one)?

Tags: vba, set, powerpoint, shapes

As far as I understand, this code "grabs" only the first shape in the active window and nudges it:

> Set oShape = oSlide.Shapes(1)
>
> oShape.Left = oShape.Left + 5

How can I "grab" all the shapes in the window and nudge them all at once?

Comment: Thanks for your editing, but I kind of don't understand why after you have edited this question, my other question, which may look similar, but in fact a different question, was gone? That was a question about how to move (nudge) only certain shapes in the active window (not all of them). For example,  if I have only 3 shapes, how can I nudge only shape 1 and shape 3, but not shape 2. That question mysteriously disappeared after your editing. Do you have any idea why it happened so?

Comment: Hey, I just realized from your editing that you "messed up" with both of my questions. This present question that you have edited and that had already been answered prior to your editing, was about "how to nudge all the present shapes in the active window (not only one)" - that's exactly what the title here says. However, you changed its whole topic by changing my last words in this question into "Let's say I have three shapes and I only want to nudge the shape number 1 and the shape number 2, how do I do it inPower Point VBA?" - that's not what I was asking about here. Can I roll back?

Comment: So, can I still ask my other question? I still don't know how to nudge only some shapes, but not all. I'll ask this question again. Hope it won't be deleted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could probably iterate through the current slide's [`Shapes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa221434(office.11).aspx) collection to set each one.

```
Dim oShape As Shape

For Each oShape In oSlide.Shapes
    oShape.Left = oShape.Left + 5
Next
```